# Consider all the six digit numbers that can be formed using the digits...

Tags: probability, permutations, combinations

Consider all the six digit numbers that can be formed using the digits 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and 6, each digit being used exactly once. Each of such six digit numbers have the property that for each digit, not more than two digits smaller than that digit appear to the right of that digit.

The examples of such numbers are 315426, 135462, 234651 ect. 
Number of the six digit numbers having desired property is:

Comment: I don't know even how to start solving this problem. no hint or idea in my mind.

Comment: question might be phrased wrong but what did you try ?

Comment: counterexample 654321 .

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee I think the OP wants to count the numbers with that property, not disprove the statement that all numbers have that property.

Comment: exactly. we have to find out the number of 6 digit numbers having desired property.

Comment: well then the use of "each of" should be eliminated because technically it could be taken as for all,  not how many.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee While I agree that the text doesn't correctly convey precicely what is meant, I would argue that on a site like this, we have to show some leeway on how literally we are to interpret broken English. Also, have you considered the following, less intrusive remedy: "Each of such six digit numbers **that** have the property that for each digit (...)" Still not perfect, but what we're after is unambiguous. Keeping in mind that many languages do not have relative pronouns, this is a very understandable mistake in my opinion.

Comment: that is used in the question before then so I don't buy it.

Comment: Judging from your comments to the posted solutions below, I think we need clarity in the definition.  All the solvers (and I ) read the condition this way:  a good string has the property for each digit, $1,\cdots, 6$ , at most two digits to the right of it are smaller than it.  Thus $234651$ is good.  Let's check:  The first digit to check is $4$...the digits less than $4$ are $3,2,1$ and of these only $1$ is to the right.  East to check $5,6$ as well.  If you are reading the definition differently, then you should clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: How many different places can the $6$ go? Once the $6$ is placed, how many different places can the $5$ go? Then keep going.

Answer (score 2):

Let it be that $s_n$ denotes the number when this is asked for digits $1,2,\dots,n$. Then for $n>3$ the following relation can be deduced:$$s_n=3s_{n-1}$$

This because as utmost left digit only $1,2,3$ are allowed, and if the utmost left digit is placed then the same problem arises for $1$ digit less.

Next to that it also obvious that $s_3=3!=6$ so we arrive at:$$s_6=3s_5=3^2s_4=3^3s_3=3^3\cdot6=162$$

Comment: sorry but i didn't understand what you want to say.

Comment: Same solution, but derived differently: The largest digit ($n$) must be one of the last three digits. Then: There are bijections between the five-digit numbers formed with 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 that have the property and the six-digit numbers that have the property, with 6 in the last position. Also bijection to the six-digit numbers that have the property, with 6 in the fifth position. And the same with 6 in the fourth position. So $s_6=3s_5$, etc.

Comment: @PriyankaVithani Do you agree that the utmost left digit can only be one of $1,2,3$?

Comment: but 654321 has the desired property

Comment: What makes you think that? First digit of $654321$ is $6$ and there are $5$ smaller digits at the right of that digit. At most $2$ are allowed.

Comment: in the question 234651 is given as example of the number showing desired property. In this number look that 1 is smaller than 6 by 4 digits, but still it is on the right of 6. I thought that question says that at the right side but only one place. this is not applied for next place. otherwise the given example 234651 will not be true.

Comment: @PriyankaVithani, the possible numbers, have form: xxxxx6,xxxx6x or xxx6xx .

Answer (score 0):

Following the hint of @Artur
6 can be only at one of the last three places. 3 possibilities
Irrespective of where 6 is 5 can also come only in one of the last 3 remaining places.
Continuing similarly we get
Total number of possibilities are: $3^4\times2=162$